# What will this recursive function yield?

Tags: c, algorithm, function

I have a recursive function `g3`, which I cannot understand what is the logic behind it, and what it actually does in general case.

```
double g3(double n) {
    if (n <= 1)
    {
        return 2;
    }
    double temp = g3(n / 2);
    return temp * temp;
}
```

- For 1 I got 2
- For 2 I got 4
- For 3 I got 16
- For 4 I got 16

Can you help me understand what it does?

Comment: What exactly do you not understand about the code? Did you run it? What did it return?

Comment: why don't you tell us what you get as the output and what part of it is the problem?

Comment: f(x) = f(x/2)^2

Comment: @CacahueteFrito ok I know that bit I'm looking for what the final value will be...

Comment: Use pencil and paper for the actual value.  That's what I would do.  Or run the code...

Comment: I used pencil and paper, take a look at my edited post...

Comment: And that's one of the reasons to avoid recursion (unless the mathematical definition of the problem to solve is itself recursive): it's harder to predict the results.

Comment: @BigSur Try more numbers.  I start seeing a rule in your numbers

Answer (score 2):

You could start by analyzing the cases, going from stop clause up, and looking not only on the "number" but what it represents:

```
g3(1) = 2 = 2^1
g3(2) = g3(1)^2 = 2^2
g3(4) = g3(2)^2 = (2^2)^2 = 2^4
g3(8) = g3(4)^2 = (2^4)^2 = 2^8
g3(16) = g3(8)^2 = (2^8)^2 = 2^16
```

So, this is pretty clear (I hope) what happens when `n = 2^k` for some integer `k`.

- Can you prove it?
- Can you repeat the process to answer what happens when `n != 2^k` for some integer `k` ?

Comment: What if `n` is not integer (`n=2.8`)?

Comment: @AlexLop. See bullet two. It could also be not a power of 2. This is a partial answer aimed to give OP direction how one can approach such problems.

Comment: I see. I missed the point that you are just leading the OP to the answer.